# Keycloak LDAP integration: using of Custom User LDAP Filter to filter by group

Tags: ldap, keycloak

I am trying to integrate LDAP Active Directory with Keycloak. I have been able to synchronize LDAP users using Custom User LDAP Filter that filters by LDAP attributes - (theAttribute=theValue). Is there a way/syntax to filter by groups? For example, say I have Active Directory group "My Group" and I want to synchronize to Keycloak only users in that group. What would be the search Custom User LDAP Filter?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about `memberOf`? For example:

```
(&(objectCategory=Person)(sAMAccountName=*)(theAttribute=theValue)(memberOf=cn=My Group,dc=example,dc=com))
```

Please refer to [RFC2254 "The String Representation of LDAP Search Filters"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2254) more details:

Comment: yes, using memberOf with the distinguishedName of my LDAP group worked!

Comment: Thanks for the format of a filter <3
The content depends on your AD/LDAP schema of course. I for one went with objectClass=organizationalPerson